# iOS - In-app purchase unknown product identifier

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, rmstore

My IAPs was working before. All of it. Some of it is live on App Store. Right now I am getting this error:

> unknown product identifier

I did not touch the code for IAPs. There is no changes in Agreements in iTunesConnect.

I did change the app name though. Can that be the problem?

What could have caused me to get this error?

Comment: Did you found a solution already? I'm experiencing the same issue for days.